# How to combine array in groovy?

Tags: groovy

The following java code exists but I'm trying to convert it to groovy.  Should I simply keep it as is w/ the System.arraycopy or does groovy have a nicer way to combine arrays like this?

```
  byte[] combineArrays(foo, bar, start) {
    def tmp = new byte[foo.length + bar.length]
    System.arraycopy(foo, 0, tmp, 0, start)
    System.arraycopy(bar, 0, tmp, start, bar.length)
    System.arraycopy(foo, start, tmp, bar.length + start, foo.length - start)
    tmp
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using lists?

Comment: If you're going to be using arrays, I'd keep it like this...no point in converting an array to a list and back again just for the sake of using some groovy style

Comment: Hey @JimmyBond07, can you check the answers and mark the best one? So people knows what worked for you?

Answer (score 63):

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = [4, 5, 6]

assert a.plus(b) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]   
assert a + b     == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: So you could do something (ugly but safe) like that

(a?:[]).plus((b?:[])) or (a?:[]) + (b?:[])

Comment: I'd do a `(a+b).findAll()`

Comment: The question is about arrays, not lists.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use an array:

```
def abc = [1,2,3,4] as Integer[] //Array
def abcList = abc as List
def xyz = [5,6,7,8] as Integer[] //Array
def xyzList = xyz as List

def combined = (abcList << xyzList).flatten()
```

Using Lists:

```
def abc = [1,2,3,4]
def xyz = [5,6,7,8]
def combined = (abc << xyz).flatten()
```

Comment: This mangles abc.  If you need abc with its original contents, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 12):

The trick is the flatten() method, that combined nested arrays into one:

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = [4, 5, 6]
def combined = [a, b].flatten()

assert combined == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

println(combined)
```

To remove null values you can use findAll() like this:

```
def a = null
def b = [4, 5, 6]
def combined = [a, b].flatten().findAll{it}

assert combined == [4, 5, 6]

println(combined)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
def a = [1, 2, 3]
def b = [4, 5, 6]
a.addAll(b)
println a
```

`>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 6):

I'd go with

```
byte[] combineArrays(foo, bar, int start) {
  [*foo[0..<start], *bar, *foo[start..<foo.size()]]
}
```

Comment: Very groovy indeed. I like it!

Comment: Instead of `foo[start..<foo.size()]`, couldn't you use `foo[start..-1]`

Comment: you could if you were working with lists.  for arrays you will have to wait till GROOVY-4665 gets fixed

Answer (score 2):

It could be done like this:

```
def newCombine(foo,bar,start) {
   ([].add + foo[0..<start]+bar+foo[start..<foo.size()]).flatten()
}
```

It works for all kinds of arrays (byte[]) or lists

Comment: I'd change your code to 
    def newCombine(foo,bar,start) {
        def res = []
        res << foo[0..<start] << bar << foo[start..<foo.size()]
        res.flatten()
    }

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions above fails if an array is undefined:

```
def a = [1,2]
def b
assert a+b == [1, 2, null]
```

which is probably not what you want.

Either test if the array exists before adding:

```
def a = [1,2,3,4]
def b // null array
def c = [0,4,null,6]
def abc = []
[a,b,c].each{ if (it) abc += it }
assert abc == [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, null, 6]
```

,or add all and then filter the output:

```
(a+b+c).findAll{ it != null }
```

(assuming here that `null` isn't a valid value in the original arrays, which implies that the first solution is a lot better, even if it may not look Groovy enough.)